# How do I parse multiple files in Python and extract important information?

Tags: python, parsing, yaml

I am trying to write a program that reads data from hundreds of YAML files repetitively and stores certain information contained in the files in a table of some sort. The program would essentially parse every YAML file in a given directory and extract the relevant information until every file has been successfully parsed.

An example of the contents of one of the YAML files:

```
%YAML:1.0
camera_rotation_wrt_base: !!opencv-matrix
  cols: 3
  data: [-0.0159428846, 0.0246045925, 0.999570131, -0.999774337, -0.0144301597, -0.0155909406,
    0.0140403481, -0.999593139, 0.024829099]
  dt: f
  rows: 3
camera_translation_wrt_base: [0.4445618987083435, 0.11700689047574997, 1.5018157958984375]
object_rotation_wrt_base: !!opencv-matrix
  cols: 3
  data: [-0.74130547, -0.0615471229, 0.668339849, 0.669196069, -0.144052029, 0.728989482,
    0.0514085107, 0.987654269, 0.147973642]
  dt: f
  rows: 3
object_rotation_wrt_camera: !!opencv-matrix
  cols: 3
  data: [-0.6565323818253673, 0.1588616842697038, -0.737379262582055, -0.07928983462501557,
    -0.9866892288165471, -0.14197683014545748, -0.7501189077886223, -0.03474571781315458,
    0.6603895951165363]
  dt: f
  rows: 3
object_translation_wrt_base: [1.1534364223480225, 0.05951927974820137, 1.3502429723739624]
object_translation_wrt_camera: [0.04407151401699165, 0.16979082390232392, 0.705698973194305]
template_id: 1965
```

I would like to be able to store the data key from the object_rotation_wrt_camera key, as well as the object_translation_wrt_camera key, in a CSV file, like so:

```
observation,rotation,translation
1,[-0.53434, 0.023343, .....],[0.54545,0.34344,....]                
2,[-0.52234, 0.3433, .....],[0.65645,0.8787344,....] 
3,[0.32234, 0.6453, .....],[0.622645,0.1787344,....]
```

In the above table, the observation number pertains to the yaml file, and therefore for each file there is an observation stored in the CSV file for both the rotation and translation variable. (note: the periods used in the table just indicate that the rotation and translation variables continue as they are quite long).

Lastly, I would like to create a final CSV file, that is similar to the one above however instead has all of the rotation and translation values separated (meaning that instead of one column for translation and one for rotation, there are 3 for translation pertaining to the 3 values within the lists of the previous CSV file, and 9 columns pertaining to each of the 9 values within the lists of the previous CSV file), like so:

```
observation,tran1,tran2,tran3,rot1,rot2,rot3,rot4,rot5,rot6,rot7,rot8,rot9
1,-0.545434,4.54545,0.343434,.............................................
2,-0.4543,3.3434,0.3534,..................................................
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stored your example in two differently files with `.yaml` endings and then ran:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import csv
import ruamel.yaml

result = [['observation', 'rotation', 'translation']]
flatres = ["observation,tran1,tran2,tran3,rot1,rot2,rot3,rot4,rot5,rot6,rot7,rot8,rot9".split(',')]
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

for idx, file_name in enumerate(Path('.').glob('*.yaml')):
   txt = file_name.read_text()
   if txt.startswith('%YAML:1.0'):
      txt = txt.replace('%YAML:1.0', "", 1).lstrip()
   data = yaml.load(txt)
   result.append([
     idx+1,
     data['object_rotation_wrt_camera']['data'],
     data['object_translation_wrt_camera'],
   ])
   row = [idx+1]
   row.extend(data['object_translation_wrt_camera'])
   row.extend(data['object_rotation_wrt_camera']['data'])
   flatres.append(row)

writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
writer.writerows(result)
print('---------')
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
writer.writerows(flatres)
```

which gives:

```
observation,rotation,translation
1,"[-0.6565323818253673, 0.1588616842697038, -0.737379262582055, -0.07928983462501557, -0.9866892288165471, -0.14197683014545748, -0.7501189077886223, -0.03474571781315458, 0.6603895951165363]","[0.04407151401699165, 0.16979082390232392, 0.705698973194305]"
2,"[-0.6565323818253673, 0.1588616842697038, -0.737379262582055, -0.07928983462501557, -0.9866892288165471, -0.14197683014545748, -0.7501189077886223, -0.03474571781315458, 0.6603895951165363]","[0.04407151401699165, 0.16979082390232392, 0.705698973194305]"
---------
observation,tran1,tran2,tran3,rot1,rot2,rot3,rot4,rot5,rot6,rot7,rot8,rot9
1,0.04407151401699165,0.16979082390232392,0.705698973194305,-0.6565323818253673,0.1588616842697038,-0.737379262582055,-0.07928983462501557,-0.9866892288165471,-0.14197683014545748,-0.7501189077886223,-0.03474571781315458,0.6603895951165363
2,0.04407151401699165,0.16979082390232392,0.705698973194305,-0.6565323818253673,0.1588616842697038,-0.737379262582055,-0.07928983462501557,-0.9866892288165471,-0.14197683014545748,-0.7501189077886223,-0.03474571781315458,0.6603895951165363
```

Because there are commas in the sequences that you want to have
stored, those entries need to be quoted and Python's CSV writer does
that automatically (otherwise the second and following rows of the CSV
would have many more than three elements).

YAML 1.0 was superseded, by YAML 1.1, in 2005 and I have not paid
special attention to the differences between those versions apart from
the directive. YAML 1.2 has been the YAML standard since 2009.
`ruamel.yaml` only supports files that have explicit YAML 1.2 (or 1.1)
directives, that is why the `%YAML:1.0` directive needs to be
explicitly removed from these files.

You might run into trouble if you have any "old-style" octal integers
in your files and in some other cases not shown in your input example.

Comment: This is extremely helpful, thanks so much! Only problem is when I try to specify ['data'] as per your recommendation, I get this error:

TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence

Comment: If you tried to do the altenternative I proposed, there was an error there, i updated that.

Comment: Okay my apologies for being vague. What I would like to do precisely is to store the rotation and translation arrays in one table (or matrix) whereby there are 2 columns, one for rotation and one for translation. Therefore each yaml file would be considered an 'observation', for example, that involves the two variables of rotation and translation.

Comment: The translation is a `list`, the rotation a `dict` (and the value for `data` in that dict is again a list. There are no arrays, table, or matrices and I have no idea what you see as difference between these three (nor if any of these three is the same as a Python list). When working with Python you should follow its terminology. Alternatively show YAML/JSON/CSV output of your expected data structure (or how it would look in python) by updating your question (and leave out "EDIT:" or any of that stuff when you do)

Comment: Thanks very much for your guidance/advice. I have updated the question and made it much more specific as to my goal I believe.

Comment: I updated my answer, CSV is of course not really a good format for nesting a list in a  cell element (which YAML and JSON do without problem).

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I have updated my question for the last time with the final thing that I would like to do. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I obliged, but this is not how stackoverflow should be used, it is a Q&A site not a remote help-me-write-a-program-for-me system. The answer to your question has become a moving target, which is unacceptable, and that primarily because you haven't thought through what you wanted to get as a result in the first place. You also haven't accepted answer to either of your other questions, and you haven't accepted mine, although I solved your problem (which you then changed)

Comment: You're completely right. My apologies as I was scrambling to develop this pose estimation algorithm last minute. In the future I will indeed take your comments into consideration. Thanks very much for your help; I have now marked the accepted answer.